# How to convert this if else structure to switch case?

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement

My IF Else Structure

```
if (e.Exception.Message.Contains("'TierType' element is invalid"))
{
    objError.ErrorCode = "EC005";
    objError.ErrorMessage = "TierType is incorrect"; //constant file      
}

else if (e.Exception.Message.Contains("'Gender' element is invalid"))
{
    objError.ErrorCode = "EC010";
    objError.ErrorMessage = "Gender is incorrect"; //constant file    
}
else
{
    objError.ErrorCode = "EC050";
    objError.ErrorMessage = e.Exception.Message;//constant file                
}
```

I need to change this structure to switch case

```
e.Exception.Message.Contains(); //this contain 10 different values
```

I try with following it's show Error

```
string Exceptionmessage = e.Exception.Message;
switch (Exceptionmessage)
{
    case Exceptionmessage.Contains("'TierType' element is invalid"):
    //case "'TierType' element is invalid":
        objError.ErrorCode = "EC005";
        objError.ErrorMessage = "TierType is incorrect";
        break;
    default:
        objError.ErrorCode ="EC050";
        objError.ErrorMessage = e.Exception.Message;
        break;
}
```

I know I try with wrong method plz tell me how to write switch structure for my requirement.

Comment: What's wrong with If/Else? As far as I'm aware, switch case labels are for equality checks.

Comment: You cannot use a contains in the switch

Comment: Why do you "need" to convert this to a `switch`?

Comment: I suppose you could do processing on your exception message first, like extract 'TierType' and 'Gender' into a string and then switch on that. But still, you should just use the If/Else.

Comment: @BossRoss if there is any alternate way available

Comment: `switch` can be used only for comparing a single variable against a collection / range of const values.

Answer (score 0):

As answered in the differents comments the switch statement requires compile time constants but if you want an alternate way, you could create a class where you initialize the list of the different exceptions you will manage.

In this class you add a method to process the exception or to manage the default exception.

Here's a way to do it :

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("'Gender' element is invalid");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error err = Error.ReadError(ex);
        }
    }
}

public class Error
{
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    public string ErrorRaw { get; set; }
    public static List<Error> ErrorList { get; private set; }

    static Error()
    {
        ErrorList = new List<Error>()
        {
            new Error(){
                ErrorCode = "EC005",
                ErrorMessage = "TierType is incorrect",  
                ErrorRaw = "'TierType' element is invalid"
            },
            new Error(){
                ErrorCode = "EC010",
                ErrorMessage = "Gender is incorrect",  
                ErrorRaw = "'Gender' element is invalid"
            },

        };
    }

    public static Error DefaultError(Exception ex)
    {
        return new Error(){
                ErrorCode = "EC050",
                ErrorMessage = ex.Message
            };
    }

    public static Error ReadError(Exception ex)
    {
        Error error = ErrorList.FirstOrDefault(e => ex.Message.Contains(e.ErrorRaw));
        if (error == null)
        {
            error = Error.DefaultError(ex);
        }

        return error;
    }
}
```